# Use variable in ODBC source in SSIS

Tags: variables, ssis, odbc, expression

i have created 3 variables in SSIS package, those are -

startTimeFormat, endTimeFormat and callProcedureQuery

callProcedureQuery is populated using an expression. The expression for that is below:

```
"call sp_ccdr ('"+ @[User::startTimeFormat]  + "', " + "'" + @[User::endTimeFormat]  + "', '0',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'NULL','NULL','f'"+ ")"
```

Now, how can I use that either in SQL Execute Task or Data Flow Task. Eventually what I want to do is the result returned by this procedure is to be transformed into a SQL Server table.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Abdulquadir